# regex windows path incomplete escape '\U'

Tags: python, regex, pathlib

I have a program that should be runnable on windows and linux systems. One function I use cuts off some root of a path and leaves me with the relative path.

```
import re
from pathlib import Path
def relative_path(absolute_absolute, root_path):
    a = str(absolute_absolute)
    r = str(root_path)
    assert re.search(r, a) is not None, (r, a)
    return Path(a.replace(r, './'))
```

It works under Linux, but under windows I get

> incomplete escape \U

The windows path looks like `C:\Users\...`.

What is the best way to deal with this? Is it OK to replace `\` with `\\`?

Comment: Yes, you need to escape the backslashes.

Comment: Closing as related (enough) to the duplicate question.  There are two actual approaches.  Either escape the backslashes, or use raw strings.